# jquery execution behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.out').each(function(index) {
       .ajax({                      
          url: "php,
          type: "GET",
          success: function(data) {
          // LOOP each dynamic textbox for my specific validation
         console.log('1'); // flag if any error
       }
    });

    // I though this will run after  $('.out').each()
    console.log('2'); // my plan is to check if atleast 1 error occur
});

result:
> 2
> 1
> 1
> 1

instead of:
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 2
```

I thought the flow will be, run the each function first which will display 1 1 1 etc, then after that it will display 2. Could anyone help me how to accomplish what I need?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unable to duplicate, I get `1 1 1 2`.

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot something, I have added my ajax then put the console.log(1) inside the ajax. Maybe the ajax has some delay and the script don't wait for the the ajax to finish. I am not sure

Comment: @Rafael - that's your problem.

Comment: You see the syntax highlighter's result and you'll know that you missed a `"` (most likely a copy error)

Comment: Move your error checking code to an `.ajaxComplete()` function.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, Ajax is asynchronous, which means that your console.log('2') statement may be executed before success function is called.

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.out').each(function(index) {
       $.ajax({                      
          url: "yourUrl.php",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(data) {
              // LOOP each dynamic textbox for my specific validation
              console.log('1'); // flag if any error
          },
          complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus){
              //This will be be called when the request finishes 
              //(after success and error callbacks are executed)
              console.log('2'); // my plan is to check if atleast 1 error occur
          }
       });
    });
});
```

Have a look here to better understand the jQuery ajax call:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you corrected the syntax errors in your code (missing `$` before `.ajax`, missing `"` on `url` value, and missing closing `});` on the `$.ajax` call, plus any other errors I didn't spot):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.out').each(function(index) {
       $.ajax({                     
          url: "php",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(data) {
            // LOOP each dynamic textbox for my specific validation
            console.log('1'); // flag if any error
          }
       });
    });

    console.log('2'); // my plan is to check if atleast 1 error occur
});
```

Then the order the statements within your ready function will be executed is first the `.each()` will call `$.ajax()` for each of the `'.out'` elements, then the `console.log('2')` at the end will be executed and the ready function will complete, then *later* the success function will be called for each Ajax request *in the order the Ajax responses are received by the browser* - which isn't necessarily the same order the Ajax requests were made. (Obviously this assumes they actually *are* successful.)

This is because Ajax requests are (supposed to be) *asynchronous* - the response callbacks will always be called after the current block of code finishes, regardless of how fast the response is received, because (ignoring web workers) JavaScript is not multi-threaded.